# How to call a method after fluent validation faliure

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I want to run a method if a fluent validation method fails.

```
RuleFor(x => x.SheepName)
            .Must(x => x.SheepName == null)
            .When(x => x.HasSheep == false)
            .Otherwise(callMethod());
```

So in this case, if the HasSheep value is false but the SheepName is still given, then I want to run a method (in the example the method is called 'callMethod()').

I have made up the .Otherwise statement, so looking for what this whole line '.Otherwise(callMethod());' needs to be..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Current version:

`OnFailure` (and `OnAnyFailure`) were removed in V11. From the [release notes](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/upgrading-to-11.html):

> If you were previously using `OnFailure` or `OnAnyFailure` to perform custom logic after validation, we recommend using a [`Custom` validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html) instead.

##### Older versions:

You can use `OnFailure(…)`, as documented [here](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#callbacks)

> You can make use of the OnAnyFailure and OnFailure (as of 8.0) callbacks to run a method if validation fails.

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.SheepName)
       .Must(x => x.SheepName == null)
       .When(x => x.HasSheep == false)
       .OnFailure(x => callMethod());
```

Comment: OnFailure is deprecated as of version 11. Wondering how to handle this without OnFailure.